# change chartSeries margin is being cut off

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod

Below are the left and right margins for my chartSeries

[image]

You can see the yaxis is being cut off.  How do I adjust the margin so the entire number appears.

```
   chartSeries(mydata, major.ticks = "minutes", TA=myTA, pars.text= list(mar = c(10,10,10,10) ))
```

I tried to do pars.text= list(mar = c(10,10,10,10) )  but that does not work. Thank you.